# Shortest Distance Between N Moving Points

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, data-structures

Given ***N*** objects on an **(x, y)** plane, each represented as  **(sx, sy, vx, vy)**, where each object starts at the point **(sx, sy)**, and moves in the direction vector **(vx, vy)**. Thus, every second the object will move **vx** units in the x direction and **vy** units in the y direction. If you were to start at the origin **(0, 0)** and move at a speed of S units/second, what is the minimum amount of time (seconds) it would take to reach all of the objects. (reaching an object is considered as occupying the same **(x, y)** coordinate as the object at a given time).

Example:

- N = 2, S = 4
- Object 1: (8, 0, -2, 0)
- Object 2: (-10, 0, -2, 0)
- Answer = 8
- Explanation: You meet the second object at **(-20, 0)** in 5 seconds. Object one is then at **(-2, 0)** and you change direction to meet at **(-8, 0)** after another 3 seconds.

I am able to solve this problem in O(N!) time, however I am interested in finding a faster algorithm.

** All given cases are supposed to be solvable/there are no impossbile cases that will be given

** The constraints for the problem are (time limits 4s, and memory limit of 256M)

- 1≤N≤15
- 0≤|sx|,|sy|≤100
- 0≤|vx|,|vy|≤10
- 1≤S≤100

It is guaranteed that all given cases are solvable

Comment: How fast of an solution do you need? This is a generalization of [Euclidean TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean), which is NP-hard, therefore this problem is also NP-hard.

Comment: I've updated the constraints, sorry for the unclairty

Comment: I believe a bitmask DP similar to one of the algorithms for the standard TSP works here. We can define `dp[mask][i]` to be a pair of the minimum and maximum times such that it is possible to visit the subset of objects represented by `mask` and end at the position of the `i`th object.

Comment: Even if the objects are not moving, visiting them all in a minimal time is Traveling Salesman Problem.